# Information not posting to Facebook page from website but will post to a new page

Tags: api, facebook-page, facebook-apps

I have a web site, [www.halfoffatthebeach.com](http://www.halfoffatthebeach.com) and the facebook app has the daily deals posting to the page automatically. It no longer works.

The software developers are not able to find anything wrong in their software, so I created a new page (now unpublished) and when that ID is entered, the deals post to the new Facebook page.

We can't figure out why the deals are posting to the new page when that ID is entered but not the existing page.  I have been manually typing the deals in.

Is anyone aware of a setting maybe that I need to change? The page is tied in to my personal account so I thought all settings would be the same for all pages as it seems I am only able to adjust the settings when using the page as myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check the two page's permissions and settings side-by-side  Since you have one that works with the third-party app, then the other must be missing something that the working one has.